# WPF Toolkit Datagrid - Can I call a function in view-model, on selection of a row?

Tags: datagrid, wpftoolkit, selection, viewmodel, row

I have a WPf Toolkit-datagrid..in my application which follows MVVM pattern.
How I can call a function in view-model if user selects a particular row in datagrid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in view

```
  <DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding MyItems}"
            SelectedItem = "{Binding MyCurrentItem}"
             >
```

in vm

```
private Myobject myCurrentItem;
public Myobject MyCurrentItem
                   {
                      get{ return myCurrentItem; }
                      set{
                            if (myCurrentItem!=value)
                            {
                               myCurrentItem=value;
                               DoMyStuff();
                            }                              
                         }
                    }
```